# List of theorems equivalent to choice

Tags: reference-request, axiom-of-choice, axioms

Can you please refer a source that you consider to contain the most complete list of statements and theorems equivalent to the axiom of choice (over the axioms of ZF)?  I am already aware of most of the equivalent statements listed on the wiki page here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice

I am most likely looking for a study or (maybe several) chapters of a book.

Comment: Have you seen the wiki page? [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents)

Comment: Yes and I am looking for something similar. But I wonder if anyone can recommend a more complete list.

Comment: There are two books. Long books. There is more research into this. There is no "complete list". But a good place to start is the Rubin & Rubin book, literally called "Equivalents of the Axiom of Choice II" (the first one is just older).

Comment: When I had Spanier at Berkeley he proved equivalence of AC,  the Maximum principle,  Zorn's lemma and the Well-ordering principle.